# ¿cómo crear un buscador con firebase en la web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, buscador, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy haciendo una red social con Firestore de firebase, pero en firebase no existe la consulta like %a% como lo hay en SQL
¿Idea para hacerlo?

La búsqueda viene de un `<input type="text">` que usa el usuario.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506531/how-to-perform-sql-like-operation-on-firebase?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

tengo esto mira

```js
ref1 = firebase.database().ref("ITLA/"+user.displayName+"/Pacientes").limitToLast(3);
ref1.once('value',function(snap){    
  datos = snap.val();
  for (k in datos){
    paciente = datos[k];
    li = $("<li></li>").attr("class", "mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--two-line");
    span1 = $("<li></li>").attr("class", "mdl-list__item-primary-content");
    img = $("<img/>").attr({
        src: paciente.foto,
        class: "material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar",
        width: "50",
        height: "50" 
    });
    p = $("<span></span>").text(paciente.nombre+" "+paciente.apellido);
    a = $("<a></a>").text("Consultas de "+paciente.nombre).attr({
        href: "#",
        id: paciente.nombre+" "+paciente.apellido,
        class: "mdl-list__item-sub-title",
        onclick: "ConsultasPaciente(this.id)"
    });
    span1.append(img, p, a);
    span2 = $("<li></li>").attr("class", "mdl-list__item-secondary-content");
    a = $("<a></a>").attr({
        href: "#",
        id: k,
        class: "mdl-list__item-secondary-action",
        onclick: "PacienteInfo(this.id)"
    });
    i = $("<i></i>").text("info_outline").attr("class", "material-icons");
    a.append(i);
    span2.append(a);
    li.append(span1, span2);
    $("#lista_pacientes").append(li);
  }
});
```